# Collision detection with jquery animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision-detection

http://jsfiddle.net/5khhmepv/31/ This is a basic game that I am in the process of making. However, after poking around on various questions on SO, I cannot, for the life of me, find a usable,simple collision detection plugin. Gamequery's is too complicated for me, and this one does not have a simple solution or good docs:http://sourceforge.net/p/jquerycollision/wiki/Home/#examples

Any suggestions? Or should I resort to coding a basic one with x, y and math stuff?

code: bullet function

```
var shoot=function(){
    if (canshoot===true) {
        canshoot=false;
        bullety=-10;
        var div = $('<div class='+'bullet'+' style="top: '+bulletTop+'px"'+'>yt</div>');
        div.appendTo('body');
        div.animate({
            left:500+'px'
        }, 1500 );
        canshoot=false;
        setTimeout(function(){ $(".bullet").hide();canshoot=true;},1500);
    }
};
```

I need collision detection between .bullet and .enemy
Thanks!

Comment: jQuery is not a game/physic engine. If you plan to do a game, you should check for more appropriate libraries.

Comment: Oh. it is just gonna be a space invaders game, pretty basic. Is there anything out there or should I abandon it?

Comment: Almost seems like you are just going to have to go with brute force. But if you are looking for some physics engine you can take a look at Physicsjs : http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/

Comment: See `step` and `progress` functions at `.animate()` options . Not certain what viewing at jsfiddle ? Can describe expected results ? Thanks